# How to rm /Volumes/Free when it is really free?

Tags: macos, finder, mount

### Short problem background

OS X version 10.10.5, running on an iMac with no problem (uptime = 101 days).
I had an USB key, named "Free" mounted on `/Volumes/Free`.
I wrote successfully a file on it, and verified it successfully with
`Disk Utility`.
Then I tried to eject it from the Finder. This operation fired the beach balloon but no message was written on `/var/log/system.log`.
After a while the Finder displayed me an error message telling me
my volume couldn't be ejected because in use.

Since I needed the USB slot to restart the copy operation on another
USB key, I ejected my USB key "Free".
And the Finder displayed me the usual error message because the volume
was unmounted incorrectly.

### Problem seen actually

I have now a directory `/Volumes/Free` which stayed in place and which I can't easily remove.

```
••On_my_Mac••% ls -@del /Volumes/Free
d--x--x--x+ 2 root  admin  102 Jul 11 14:01 /Volumes/Free
 0: group:everyone inherited deny add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit
••On_my_Mac••%
```

Neither `Spotlight` nor any other daemon stayed with this directory opened:

```
••On_my_Mac••% /usr/bin/sudo lsof /Volumes/Free
••On_my_Mac••%
```

Nonetheless I get the following error upon trying to remove it:

```
••On_my_Mac••% /usr/bin/sudo rm -rf /Volumes/Free
rm: /Volumes/Free/.autodiskmounted: Permission denied
rm: /Volumes/Free: Permission denied
••On_my_Mac••%
```

If I further try to analyze this filesystem problem, I get:

```
••On_my_Mac••% /usr/bin/sudo chmod u+rw /Volumes/Free
••On_my_Mac••% /usr/bin/sudo ls -@ael /Volumes/Free
ls: fts_read: Permission denied
••On_my_Mac••% /usr/bin/sudo ls -@del /Volumes/Free/.autodiskmounted
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  0 Jul 11 14:01 /Volumes/Free/.autodiskmounted
••On_my_Mac••%
```

I didn't try a reboot because this is not a short term an option on the server involved.

---

Which daemon is responsible of this situation?

How may I further analyze this problem?

Comment: What's the output of: `ls -@el /Volumes/Free/.autodiskmounted`

Answer (score 1):

You tried the command given below.

/usr/bin/sudo rm -rf /Volumes/Free

Try entering the following.

```
sudo sh
/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rf /Volumes/Free
exit
```

Comment: This command is giving the same error:••return••
rm: /Volumes/Free/.autodiskmounted: Permission denied••return••
rm: /Volumes/Free: Permission denied

Comment: BTW, what should do this `bypass` command?